# Java Protected Access Not Working

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility, protected, access-levels

In java, there's three levels of access:

- Public - Open to the world
- Private - Open only to the class
- Protected - Open only to the class and its subclasses (inheritance).

So why does the java compiler allow this to happen?

TestBlah.java:

```
public class TestBlah {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blah a = new Blah("Blah");
        Bloo b = new Bloo("Bloo");
        System.out.println(a.getMessage());
        System.out.println(b.getMessage()); //Works
        System.out.println(a.testing);
        System.out.println(b.testing); //Works
    }
}
```

Blah.java:

```
public class Blah {
    protected String message;

    public Blah(String msg) {
        this.message = msg;
    }

    protected String getMessage(){
        return(this.message);
    }   
}
```

Bloo.java:

```
public class Bloo extends Blah {
    public Bloo(String testing) {
        super(testing);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also package access.  It is the default with no modifier.

Comment: are you sure that's right - a.testing and b.testing are not declared.

did you mean a.message and b.message?

Comment: There are four levels of access. Works as designed.

Comment: I was hoping Java would have the access similar to C++ and C#. +1 for the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually it should be:

> Open only to the [**classes on the same package**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) the  class and its subclasses (inheritance)

That's why

Answer (score 11):

Because protected means subclass *or* other classes in the same package.

And there's actually a fourth "default" level of access, when the modifier is omitted, which provides access to other classes in the same package.

So `protected` is between default and `public` access.

Answer (score 5):

To be more specific, you're expecting `protected` to work as it does in C++.

However, in Java, it has a different meaning.  In Java, a protected method is available to the class (obviously), all the other classes in the same package and any subclasses of this class.  Classes in other packages will not have access unless they subclass this original class.

[See this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private) for more specific information on inheritance markers.

Personally, I almost never use `protected`.  I develop applications rather than frameworks so I'm much more likely to define `public` methods, `private` data and, quite often, mark my whole class as `final`.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually four levels of access: "public", "protected", "private" & default also known as package private or package protected. Default limits accessibility to the package. Default is quite useful and I use it frequently.

Answer (score 3):

You're able to call `b.getMessage()` because `b` is of type `Bloo`, which extends `Blah`, and `getMessage()` is protected.  Protected, as you mentioned, allows subclasses to access the method.

You've got the following errors, though:

- Calling `super()` with no arguments in the `Bloo` constructor is an error.  The compiler can't find the no-parameter `Blah` constructor because you defined one with a String parameter.
- Calling `new Blah()` in `TestBlah` `main` method is an error for the same reason as above.
- Referring to `a.testing` and `b.testing` is an error because you didn't define the variable `testing` for any class.

Comment: He heh I gues I'll never know if he did that on purpose. Hey that's funny the lizard answering to the dragon. :)