# java - protected members accessed in derived class using base class instance

Tags: java, protected, access-control

I created instance of base class in derived class and tried to access protected members.

I can directly access protected members in a derived class without instantiating the base class.

Base class:

```
package com.core;

public class MyCollection {

      protected Integer intg;
}
```

A derived class in the same package -

```
package com.core;

public class MyCollection3 extends MyCollection { 

 public void test(){

  MyCollection mc = new MyCollection();
  mc.intg=1; // Works
 }
}
```

A derived class in a different package -

```
package secondary;

import com.core.MyCollection;

public class MyCollection2 extends MyCollection{ 

 public void test(){
  MyCollection mc = new MyCollection();
  mc.intg = 1; //!!! compile time error - change visibility of "intg" to protected
 }
}
```

How it is possible to access a protected member of a base class in a derived class using instance of base class when derived class is also in same package but not when derived class is in different package?

If I mark protected member as "static" then I am able to access protected member of base class using instance of base class in a derived class which resides in a different package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Protected Access Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332920/java-protected-access-not-working) --- Actually that's the wrong dupe! Sorry! This is definitely a dupe though.

Comment: don't worry, your IDE won't make any difference to the question as this is about the semantics of the Java language itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why can't i access protected java method even thought i've extended the class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622219/why-cant-i-access-protected-java-method-even-thought-ive-extended-the-class)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right that you can't do this.  The reason why you can't access the field, is that you're not in the same package as the class, **nor are you accessing an inherited member of the same class**.

The last point is the critical one - if you'd written

```
MyCollection2 mc = new MyCollection2();
mc.intg = 1;
```

then this would work, as you're changing a protected member of *your own* class (which is present in that class through inheritance).  However, in your case you're trying to change a protected member of a **different** class in a different package.  Thus it should come as no surprise that you're denied access.

Comment: This explanation is really easy to understand.
I had a look at java language specification and their elaboration went over my head!!!

Comment: @Tarun - if an answer has worked for you, mark it as accepted (tick below the vote counter)

Comment: I did not know this feature. I would mark it as answered now.

Comment: @Doyle I think this answer does make sense, but you might ignore that why we can access mc.intg if we make intg static in MyCollection

Answer (score 3):

The [Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) says:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

And in your case, you are accessing the variable in another object. By coincidence it has a class that's the same as the current one, but the visibility checks wouldn't check that.

So, the second time you are denied access, because you are in a different package, and the first time you are given access because you are in the same package (and not because it's a subclass)

Comment: "first time you are given access because you are in the same package (and not because it's a subclass)"

This makes it clear for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If a class member is `protected` then there are 2 cases:

> 1. If subclass is in same package
> 2. If subclass is in different package
>
> I. Same package :
>   - Can access through inheritance
>   - Can access by creating an instance of parent class
>   II. Different package :
>   - Can **only** access through inheritance

See the table below for all use cases:

[image]

Source: SCJP book.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it's not really possible. It seems like you should reconsider your design.

However, there's a work around, if you're sure that's what you want to do. You can add a protected *method* to `MyCollection` which takes an instance and sets the value of `intg` on your behalf:

```
package com.core;

public class MyCollection {

    protected Integer intg;

    protected void setIntg(MyCollection collection, Integer newIntg) {
        collection.intg = newIntg;
    }
}
```

Now your subclasses can access this method:

```
package secondary;

import com.core.MyCollection;

public class MyCollection2 extends MyCollection{ 

    public void test(){
        MyCollection mc = new MyCollection();
        setIntg(mc, 1);
    }
}
```

But please note that this is a *very* strange way of doing it. I'd suggest again that your design needs to be rethought before you go down this route.

Comment: I get your point.
Most easy way for me would have been to directly access the protected member than instantiating base class and accessing it in a different package.
I did it "mistakenly" while playing with java (did not I say I have been a manaul tester :-)) and then none of my dev member was able to provide me conceivable answer. So I posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

According to the member accessibility rule of Java you cannot access protected member of a class without extending it.

You can try the following.

```
package secondary;

import com.core.MyCollection;

public class MyCollection2 extends MyCollection{ 

 public void test(){
  intg = 1; 
 }
}
```

Instead of creating the new instance try to assign the value. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant access a protected variable in a derived class (which is in different package) if accessed using a new object of class MyCollection.
you can just write intg = 1; directly without making ( new MyCollection )
like this:

```
package secondary;
import com.core.MyCollection;       
public class MyCollection2 extends MyCollection{ 

 public void test(){

     intg = 1;

 }
}
```