# inheritance and protected class java

Tags: java

error: mul(int,int) has protected access in Multiplication

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Multiplication{
            protected int mul(int a,int b){
                return (a*b);
            }
        }

        class ImplimentPkg extends Multiplication {
            public static void main(String args[]){

                Multiplication obj=new ImplimentPkg();
               //Here's the error
                System.out.println(obj.mul(2,4));

            }
            protected int mul(int a,int b){

                    System.out.println("");
                    return 0;
                }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly "Here's the error"?

Comment: System.out.println(obj.mul(2,4)) is not able to access its own method..which is overridden..!

Comment: Is the class `ImplimentPkg` in a different package from `Multiplication`? If yes, the error occurs because `mul` is protected and you cannot access it from another package.

Comment: why cant we acces form other package?? if i am not wrong we can use inheritance with procted method?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create each class in its own Java file

ImplimentPkg.java

```
package my;

class ImplimentPkg extends Multiplication {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Multiplication obj = new ImplimentPkg();
        System.out.println(obj.mul(2, 4));

    }

    protected int mul(int a, int b) {

        System.out.println("");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Multiplication.java

```
package my;

public class Multiplication {
    protected int mul(int a, int b) {
        return (a * b);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing this in different package.
I want that way .whare is the problem please help?

Comment: if they are in different packages, then you cannot use protected by definition. You'll have to use public instead.

Comment: @Leo that's not the answer what Pushpak is asking.

Answer (score 2):

[Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) says:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

You may think you have matched the second case(inheritence).

```
Multiplication obj = new ImplimentPkg();
System.out.println(obj.mul(2, 4));
```

This means you are using an instance of parent class Multiplication. Although the code is inside a method of subclass of Multiplication. It doesn't mean the instance obj has something to do with **inheritance**. And of course the mul(...) method is invisible. What you can do is: use keyword **super.**

```
public void bar() {
    Multiplication mul = new Multiplication();
    mul.mul(1, 2);  // <- error
    super.mul(1, 2); // correct
    Multiplication.foo(); // correct
}
```

Note: if you have protected static method in parent class, like:

```
public class Multiplication {
    private String name = "some";

    protected int mul(int a, int b) {
        return (a * b);
    }

    protected static void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}
```

Here the foo() method can be accessed everywhere in subclass, but not other classes. By the way, you shouldn't use **protected static** method, see [reasons here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289070/why-we-should-not-use-protected-static-in-java).

Another related topic may be interested to you, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148600/java-protected-members-accessed-in-derived-class-using-base-class-instance/29226054#29226054).